# Smarty - less comparison different numbers

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

I want to compare prices. if one price is lesser than another price the template should put out some html.

I think it could be a bug in smarty.

When i compare:

```
if 69,95€ < 125,95€
```

Smarty returns **false**.
When i compare:

```
if 69,95€ < 99,95€
```

it returns **true**. 
And when i compare:

```
if 149,95€ < 199,95€
```

It's **true** too.

It looks like smarty thinks that a two digit number, like 90 is not less than than a three digit number, like 120.

Why is that so? Has anyone a clue?

Comment: Because you compare strings, not numbers?

Comment: Using `<` or `>` on (non-numeric) strings will result in a character-by-character comparison. Six is greater than one, so any string starting with six will be greater than any that starts with 1. You need to convert your prices to a numeric type, and format them as prices when you display them.

Comment: Thanks iainn, that's the answer. I removed the Euro-sign and replaced the comma with a dot. Now it works!